# Vonage developer use phone number as Sip endpoint

Tags: vonage

I have Vonage SIP information that using apikey + apisecret + vonage domain to register SIP, now I want to test the virtual number that I bought from Vonage Developer. I tried to using Zoiper5 softphone, it's success to register SIP but can not get incoming call when I tried to call to this number. Does someone meet this problem?